# How to add Encoding type in FormData()?

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data

Following is my Javascript code, where I would like to set the content type as "multipart/form-data". Help me with how this can be done? Thanks

```
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
var formData = new FormData();
for(var i=0;i<file.files.length;i++)
    formData.append("nodeDoc[]", file.files[i]);
formData.append('userId', readCookie('userId'));
formData.append('passwd', readCookie('passwd'));
formData.append('treeType', selectedTreeType);
formData.append('displayName', document.getElementById('displayName').value);
formData.append('nodeType', document.getElementById('nodeType').value);  
formData.append('attrList', constructAttrList());
client.open("post", serverUrl + "node/addNode", true);
client.send(formData);
 console.log("/node/addNode API called with file");
```

Comment: @KVK Doesn't it go as a data with name 'enctype'?

Comment: What do you mean by "encryption type"?

Comment: What is `client`, an XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: @Bergi Edited my question. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, you mean *encoding*, not encryption.

Comment: @Bergi Yes. I dont want to specify it in html, how do I do it in Javascript in the code shown above?

Comment: I don't think you need to, do you? What header is sent by your current code?

Answer (score 0):

> `client.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");`

Comment: Try with client.setRequestHeader("Content-type",undefined);

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set the multipart/form-data manually. it is automatically set by FormData.

From MDN blog

> *The transmitted data is in the same format that the form's submit() method would use to send the data if the form's encoding type were set
>   to multipart/form-data.*

Link for same
[FormData Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)